# Some websites won't load on Chrome Canary, ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: twitter, google-chrome, browser

Some websites' assets fail to load on Chrome Canary, i.e:

```
 GET https://abs.twimg.com/a/1547701933/css/t1/twitter_more_1.bundle.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

Accessing 
https://abs.twimg.com/a/1547701933/css/t1/twitter_core.bundle.css directly
returns:

```
This site can’t be reached 
abs.twimg.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

This also happens on Guest Account without any extensions.
All works on normal Chrome version.

Faulty Canary version:

```
Google Chrome is up to date
Version 73.0.3678.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can report this bug directly to Chrome developers here:

> [image: 1]
>
> **[https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/](https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/?token=wrdLx4uRUNV9omU7L9nyKToxNTM5MjE2MDAw&role=&continue=https%3A//bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry.do)**
>
> **[https://dev.chromium.org/bug-reporting-guidelines/](https://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines)**

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem. It seems to be related to [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=923273&q=This%20site%20can%E2%80%99t%20be%20reached&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)